# How to do redirection in an app hosted in multiple regions

Tags: redirect, geolocation, digital-ocean

We need to support clients in Europe and Asia (Australia) so hosting our app in 1 region is not great due to long latency. So we have the web app hosted in 2 regions, EU and Asia and also added a read replica of the database to further increase latency.

Now the question is, if we want to use URL for the website say https://example.com. How do I make sure that the european customers goes to Web app 1 in Europe and asian customers go to the site hosted in asia?

I have read about Geo Redirect which can redirect to the correct site based on ip. I dont know if this is correct approach. Also what if I'd like to redirect based on a cookie, say I'm currently in EU but on the settings page on the site, I set my location to Asia - then I'd like it to go to asia despite of the ip.

Hope someone with experience in this area can shed some light on this, thanks!

Lastly a little drawing of the current setup:

[image]

Comment: Which exactly GCP and AWS services are you using?

Comment: Currently im using a higher level layer, digital ocean platform to host app and db in different regions

Comment: Thank you. Please **do not use unrelated tags** next time just to get more attention to your question. I deleted unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similiar problem, it turns you only need 1 web app (if there's a global CDN available which there is for Digital Ocean) and you manage inside the web app which backend to point to :)